# How to specify multiple .pdf links to open easely on cordova?

Tags: cordova, pdf, hyperlink, phonegap

Im doing my first mobile-hyprid app on android. Im using cordova / phonegap. My html contains multiple .pdf files that i'd like to open. Site is like guide to other workers with jpg and .pfd manuals.

I was searching all over stack and other sites to help this problem, but i really dont know how to do it correctly. I found many sollutions that opens one pdf file, but that needs many lines of javascript. Can i do it like every .pdf opens adobe pdf reader or Innappbrowser or something else. My files are now local but i can upload them to my server and use url links.

My site contains about 100 .pdf links and .jpg 
.jpg opens nicely with featherlight.js.

My code look like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <h2 class="blokki">ED / EDB Vaunut</h2>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h4>Piirikaaviot</h4>
            <h4 class="linkki"><a href="#a" data-toggle="collapse">ICS01 28001 - 28020 & 28401 - 28410</a></h4>
            <div id="a" class="collapse">
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/IY710001.pdf" target="_blank">1. 1500 V rev.D)</a></p>
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/IY710003.pdf" target="_blank">3. 230 V rev.H</a></p>
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/IY710004.pdf" target="_blank">4. Lämmitys ja ilmastointi rev.G</a></p>
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/IY710005.pdf" target="_blank">5. Valaistus rev.G</a></p>   
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/IY710006.pdf" target="_blank">6. 110V ja 24V rev.I</a></p>  
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/IY710007.pdf" target="_blank">7. Vaunumikro rev.G</a></p> 
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/IY710008.pdf" target="_blank">8. Informaatiolaitteet rev.G</a></p>
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/geijer_hissi.pdf" target="_blank">Geijer hissi</a></p>  
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/rejlers_nostin.pdf" target="_blank">Rejlers-nostin</a></p>    
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/ed_pc_pistorasiat.pdf" target="_blank">Ed PC-pistorasiat</a></p>    
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/edb_pc_pistorasiat.pdf" target="_blank">Edb PC-pistorasiat</a></p>    
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/wlan_ed_01_02.pdf" target="_blank">Ed/Edb 01/02-sarja Jwlan</a></p>    
                <p class="rivitys"><a href="content/ed/piirikaaviot/ics01/doc_0024659_1_liite_5_ed_edb_ja_eds_vaunut_kytkennat_ed.pdf" target="_blank">WTB-kaapelointimuutos</a></p>
```

Im using collapse menus, which opens dropdown like list with my .pdf files.

This is my first project so im kind of noob. Please help! Mobilesite works nicely, but .app doesnt cause of .pdf problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this native document viewer [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/document-viewer/).

Comment: Thx for fast response! Few questions : how i include this: viewDocument(url, contentType, options, onShow, onClose, onMissingApp, onError) to my href links? Can i use ionic plugin without ionic? And last, where do i put that Usage code on document viewer page?